# I am getting this error while running Javafx Gluon

Tags: java, javafxports

New project -> Gluon -> Gluon Mobile ->Single View Project and set gradle open project

Error:(10, 0) Could not get unknown property 'iosClasses' for task set.
[image: image description here]
[image: image description here]

Comment: Post you full build.gradle file here

Comment: how to add i dont know

Comment: Just copy-paste the whole contents of `build.gradle` file located in the root of your project.

Comment: too long by 258 characters

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {jcenter()}
    dependencies {classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.5'}}
apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
 maven {url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'}
}
mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'
dependencies {compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.2'}

Comment: jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.2.4'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'}
    ios {infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*']
}}

Comment: These comments don't help. You can edit your question and post it there (and remove the comments). What task where you running? Have you used the right Gradle tab, with any of the tasks `tasks->build->clean` and `tasks->build->build`, or `tasks->application->run`? Do they work for you?